# Why do I have to pass an empty namespace to XPathNavigator.GetAttribute?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xpathnavigator

Given the following XML markup:

```
<root xmlns="Demo">
    <child name="foo"/>
</root>
```

and an `XPathNavigator` positioned on the `<child>` element,

```
string withNs = navigator.GetAttribute("name", navigator.NamespaceURI);
string withoutNs = navigator.GetAttribute("name", "");
```

produce strange results: `withNs` is empty, `withoutNs` contains `foo`.

Why is that? I would have expected it would be the other way round, as the `name` attribute must be in the `Demo` namespace like the `child` element.

The MSDN documentation does not mention any magic meaning of passing `namespaceURI=""`, so I assumed you have to pass the real namespace URI of the attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> as the `name` attribute must be in the `Demo` namespace like the `child` element.

Attributes do not inherit the namespace of the element to which they belong, as per the w3c specification, and that is why you got those results, which are correct.

Related article: http://web.archive.org/web/20170118162309/http://www.xmlplease.com/attributexmlns